# python scraping google, getting requests.Response obj with unknown encoding, can't read anything everything is encrypted

Tags: web-scraping, firefox, python-requests, vpn, python-3.8

I am not sure why this happens, I looked up everywhere this problem, but for some reason I feel like only I have this problem.

```
def initSess(url):
    headersDt, cookiesDt = getdts('requirements/headers.txt'); Req = Request('GET', url, headers=headersDt, cookies=cookiesDt)
    Sess = Session(); Preq = Sess.prepare_request(Req)
    return Sess, Preq


def getsource():
    url = 'https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=awd'

    Sess, Preq = initSess(url)
    Resp = getResp(Sess, Preq)
    print()
```

As you can see when I search on google for the word 'awd', I send the request to google and get a response obj.

The Resp.text consists of encrypted data for some reason (never had this problem with any other site), like:

> ��Z�}��AkR�F����g������������}WH�;��P�20L�9y,5��,O�����4dvr<�R����q�)��e��@�G�/����"�8�&d@�́{��z

As you can see, this is disgusting, and i tried decoding the bytes from the response obj with all possible encoding types, but nothing worked. I also tried chardet, and it couldn't identify the encoding used.

The headers.txt contains the following data:

```
Host: www.google.com 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64;x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0 
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8 
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5  
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br 
Connection: keep-alive  
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1  
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document 
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate  
Sec-Fetch-Site: none  
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
```

The contents of the txt are properly formatted, then read and used as a dict. I checked it several, several times already. If there is an error of my copy paste of the txt in this post, then it is due to formatting which I might have not noticed, but in the program it is properly imported.

I have tried using Cookies in the headers and consequently in the Request object, but the problem is the same -> I get bytes with unknown encodings.

I feel like it is done on purpose to find bots, because I found one little thing in the response header when I use the firefox browser:

```
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

The last time i checked, everything was the same in the received response object in python, except this one little line. As far as i know, this is an important protocol that google uses for firefox.

My theory is that google is somehow capable to find out if I am using firefox or not. Even if I am using proper headers, user agents and what not. Moreover from what I read, google removes a large chunk of the request headers (that the server is receiving) so there is a great scale of data manipulation going on from their side, by which they are precisely able to determine my 'browser'.

What i find interesting, is that there are no people complaining about this issue. On the opposite. People have success scraping google links. That causes me to doubt my theory and I might be screwing up somewhere.

I am not sure if this is relevant, but I would like to mention that I am using a VPN also.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> My theory is that google is somehow capable to find out if I am using firefox or not.

That's because your url states that you are using the firefox browser `url = 'https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=awd'`.

Could you try to change the url to `https://www.google.com/search?q=awd` instead? The `client=firefox-b-d` is used for Mozilla to receive remuneration from Google and *may* be causing the issue.

Comment: I already attempted the request without the client=firefox parameter, the problem was the same.

This is just something new I tried adding.

Comment: 'That's because your url states that you are using the firefox browser' - isn't that the point? To make google believe I am using firefox?

Answer (score 0):

To make Google believe that you're using Firefox you need to add [Firefox `user-agent`](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/firefox/) to request `headers` (*no `Session()` object is needed if you don't want to*) instead:

```py
headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
}

requests.get("URL", headers=headers)
```

Have a look at the [list of `user-agents`](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/), and check [what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

---

Alternatively, you can use [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi to forget to think about it. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference is that you don't have to think about how to bypass blocks from Google or other search engines, how to parse certain elements from the HTML or JavaScript, or why certain things don't work as they should.

Example code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = { 
  "q": "Dovahkiin",          # query
  "hl": "en",                # language
  "gl": "us",                # country to search from
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"]:
   title = result["title"]
   link = result["link"]
   
   print(title, link, sep="\n")
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.